# A day for bad questions

Tags: support, off-topic

Mods,  can you please review the recent questions for today:

- [Isn't running with a side stitch going to hurt our body?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/6290/isnt-running-with-a-side-stitch-going-to-hurt-our-body)
- [The millenium goals of UN can be reached?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/6289/the-millenium-goals-of-un-can-be-reached)
- [Is it true that putting unripe pears on cardboard will help them ripen faster?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/6287/is-it-true-that-putting-unripe-pears-on-cardboard-will-help-them-ripen-faster)
- [Has radiological dating been tested and falsified?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/6286/has-radiological-dating-been-tested-and-falsified)
- [Can eating too much sugar cause diabetes?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/6284/can-eating-too-much-sugar-cause-diabetes)
- [Are there any toxic or dangerous food pairings?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/6283/are-there-any-toxic-or-dangerous-food-pairings)

They all appear to be off-topic or not noteworthy.

---

This site has some serious issues:

Try and guess which one of these questions is from our site, and which one is from Yahoo answers:

- [Can you really be suffocated from being smothered by a pillow?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/6293/can-you-really-be-suffocated-from-being-smothered-by-a-pillow)
- [If someone tries to suffocate you with a pillow, will your nose bleed from that or does it have to break?](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20101001103521AA9amVN)

Comment: The pillow question is just not very good. I don't think it should be closed outright though. The sugar/diabetes one is a very common claim. It's an easy question and we should also have some of those. The food pairings one is a list question only if such pairings are common. Are they?

Comment: @sklivvz - Mentos and Mountain Dew, Aspirin and Coke. These are all valid answers to the question. But they suck.

Comment: The problem with this site is the mods seem to think that mediocre questions shouldn't be closed outright even though they are not very good.

Comment: It's not an *explicit* list question. It's not "let's list all the possible pairings of foods which are toxic". It's "are there any>". So we should give it the benefit of doubt.

Comment: Not-so-good questions which are otherwise valid should be downvoted and not closed, imho. Can you provide an example of a question that should only be downvoted and not closed, otherwise?

Comment: @sklivvz - I fail to see the difference. Do you mean by "are there any" that it only requires one answer?

Comment: yes. It is a "yes/no" question.

Comment: @sklivvz - not so good questions should always be closed. Good questions that are off topic should perhaps be down voted. But as a high rep user or a mod anything worth down voting is an almost certain candidate for closure. That's our job to keep poor questions away from the site. By keeping these open and u guys hardly ever go back over these "wait and see" questions, u just encourage more of the same.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1414/discussion-between-sklivvz-and-xiaohouzi79)

Comment: @sklivvz - Having problems with an old cookie and logging in. Trying to get there now.

Comment: @xiaohouzi79 Where in the FAQ does it say you can't ask a mediocre question/mediocre questions should be closed? I understand if it frustrates you, but closing mediocre questions isn't really going to help the site gain popularity. IMHO, it's a deterrent. If someone comes to the site and a bunch of questions are closed, that isn't very encouraging.

Comment: @MatthewKeirstead - The aim of the SE network is to make the internet a better place, being popular is a secondary goal. The aim is not to be Yahoo answers, but a resource for finding accurate information to real questions. If I want enjoyment from odd questions asked by weirdos I listen to http://mbmbam.com/ If I want to find serious answers to serious questions I should be getting them here.

Comment: @xiaohouzi79 Sure, that's fine. How is my pear ripening question poor though? It's certainly not the most serious question on the site, and it would seem that almost no one has heard of this particular claim before, so why not? Where would you rather I ask? I choose not to waste my time on WikiAnswers or Yahoo! Answers because they generally don't generate many helpful answers.

Comment: @MatthewKeirstead - There was a decision made to only have noteworthy questions on this site, because anyone can make up any claim. "My friends told me to wrap apples in toilet paper to increase vitamin A". Why is that bad? Because there is no facts to dispute it; because people who _could_ answer this have better things to do with their time. Bad questions = bad answers. Your accepted answer is still just speculation, there's no facts to back it up.

Comment: @MatthewKeirstead - That being said, I am just one person and your question still stands. It seems anything goes on this site now, so feel free to ignore the above. The community as a whole decides what is valid and what isn't. I'm just offering one side of a discussion.

Comment: @MatthewKeirstead - Any question will be looked at seriously on this site, this is due to the quality of people on the site, but if you lower the quality of the questions, you also lower the quality of the people. If you start bringing Yahoo type questions to the site then you are going to get the same poor quality answers on the site because people like myself don't want to bother looking at those types of questions. Your questions is not terrible, but its bad because it won't be answered properly.

Comment: @xiaohouzi79 I dearly hope that you don't think that I make up questions to gain rep/for the sake of doing thus. If an official decision was made, as you say, then I agree with you. But I also think that if that decision was made, then they should modify the FAQ to reflect that.

Comment: @MatthewKeirstead - That's definitely not my point at all. We want people to come to this site to find precise answers to real questions. Your question is a real question, however how can someone looking at your answer be sure it is 100% fact? To quote from your answer: "...I have decided..." the site is not supposed to be based on your own assumptions, but all answers should be backed by references. Are you 100% sure that your answer is not spreading more inaccurate information? For a skeptics site, that is a terrible thing.

Comment: @MatthewKeirstead - I suggest you read these two questions: [Must all questions be notable](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/864/faq-must-all-questions-be-notable) [Must all answers be referenced](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/5/faq-must-all-answers-be-referenced)

Comment: @xiaohouzi79 I made the answer as a starting point. It's community wiki, so anyone can edit it if they so desire. Thanks for the links, btw.

Comment: Meta is the new chat? :) I downvoted, because collecting all those questions in one meta question isn't helpful. For close-discussions, every thread should be viewed separately, or the common reason should be named - posted on the same day is a bad reason to close all of them. Discussing 6 different threads will end in a mess.

Comment: @user unknown - if the mods did there job I wouldn't need to post here at all. Why put these in 6 different questions? They are all obviously off topic.

Comment: If you think they're off topic, flag them, and make a comment. Always starting a thread on meta will increase the trash, not decrease it.

Comment: @user - I have previously flagged posts and they get rejected even if they get closed. So what's the point. Don't u think making 6 different meta posts as you've suggested would make even more "trash"?

Comment: In a clear case, vote to close. If unclear, start a discussion, but one per case, then it will not be trash.

Comment: @user - Sir, your point is pointless

Answer (score 1):

I've closed the radiological question as not a real question. Carbon dating is very very commonly used in science. If you disbelieve that, what are you going to accept as an answer? It's certainly a notable claim though.

More in general: since skepticism is based on the scientific method and empirical evidence, any question that doubts those is either "not a real question" or borderline so. There's possibly a much better way of asking such questions, e.g. by bringing evidence to the table: "Experiment XYZ is claimed to prove that carbon dating is inconsistent. Is this true?". The difference is that this question is about "experiment XYZ" and not carbon dating.

Answer (score 0):

The first two are closed now.

The fruit ripening question is probably notable, at least there is a very similar common claim and I asked the OP to clarify

That radiological dating produces wrong results is commonly claimed by creationists, so I'd say it is notable.

The link between diet and diabetes is much more complicated than just "eating sugar = bad", so I think the question is notable.

The list nature of the dangerous food pairings question is a bit problematics, but it is cerainly on-topic and notable. It might be better as a question about a specific food pairing, but I don't see a reason to close it in the current form.

Comment: For the diabetes: It's not more complicated than poor diet is a risk factor for diabetes and the full answer to the question can be found easily. It doesn't deserve debate, its simple research.

Comment: For the dangerous pairings: It breaks the system. If everyone suggests their pairs, there's no way for these to be assessed individually. It's just a list question. Like list your favourite music. Except this is worse, because you are asking people to provide more questions as answers to a question.

Comment: For the dating: This question has serious problems as there are several types of dating. You can't ask "does travel cause hairloss" if you don't specify the type of travel. This question is overly broad. Ask me a broad enough question and I can find a edge case where it is false. I bet I can find a case of scientific dating that is not 100% accurate, but is that the most common one? If it isn't is it worth mentioning? You are just giving fuel to idiots.

Comment: @xiao all radiological dating is based on the same basic physics, I clarified the question to mean consistent wrong results as implied in the first paragraph to avoid hunting for the exceptions.

Comment: "I disbelieve physics and I bring no evidence to the table" -> FAIL